# Sencha error "console is not defined"

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to fetch some post form my WordPress blog in my Sencha application.

But I keep on getting this error "consle is not defined".

Hare is my code for different files.

App.js

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
'Ext': 'touch/src',
'ov_app': 'app'
});


Ext.application({
name: 'ov_app',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],
profiles: ['Phone', 'Tablet', 'Desktop'],
views: ['Main', 'Eligibelity', 'HeaderBar', 'ListNavigation', 'FooterBar', 'home_button', 'main_navigation', 'Corporateclints', 'Question_form', 'Quick_Enquiry', 'sinlgepost'],
stores: ['NavigationItems', 'GetContent'],
models: ['Items', 'PostContent', 'MainNavigation' ],

controllers: ['MainController'],

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    ov_app.container = Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('ov_app.view.Main'));
},
});
```

GetContent.js

```
Ext.define('ov_app.model.PostContent', {
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
config:{
    fields: [
        {name: 'content'}
        ]
    }
});
```

GetContent.js

```
Ext.define('ov_app.store.GetContent', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config:{
    model: 'ov_app.model.PostContent',
    autoLoad :true,
    proxy:{
        type:'jsonp',
        url:'http://www.one-visa.com/api/get_post/?id=2798',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'post'
        },
    }
}
});
```

sinlgepost.js

```
Ext.define('ov_app.view.sinlgepost', {
xtype:'sinlgepost',
extend:'Ext.Container',
config:{
    xtype: 'data',
    store: 'getcontent',
    itemTpl: '<p>{content}</p>'
}
});
```

I really not getting any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code of the exact line on which the error is triggered? My bet would be that you're using `console.log(...)` or something similar, in a browser that doesn't expose `window.console` (I think IE does not).

Comment: I am using chrome. Yes you are right it was cumming due to console.log(). But still after removing it I am getting blank screen.

Comment: Is there any way I can check the data returned by proxy or loaded in the store?

Comment: Never encountered this error with chrome. Maybe ensure that the debugger tools are always opened. You can also use the `debugger` keyword in your code, that will pause the execution and let you inspect the content of surrounding variables.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help but could you pleas tell me is there something wrong with my above code or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The error "consle is not defined" has clearly pointed out the mistake you've made: if you want to access the `console` object, its name is `console` not `consle`.